# Position sticky relative to parent to parent container

Tags: css, sass

I need a sticky header relative to parent div. Currently, Header is sticky only on a section div.
But I want a sticky header relative to a parent class.

HTML code

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="section-one">
      <h1>Header 1</h1>
      <div class="content">
         content 123
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="section-two">
      <h1>Header 2</h1>
      <div class="content">
         content 789
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="section-three">
      <h1>Header 3</h1>
      <div class="content">
         content 456
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is my css,

```
.parent {
   position: relative;
}
.section-one h1{
   position: sticky;
   top: 0;
   z-index: 9999;
}
.section-two h1{
   position: sticky;
   top: 50;
   z-index: 9999;
}
.section-three h1{
   position: sticky;
   top: 100;
   z-index: 9999;
}
```

I want a sticky header as per below

```
Header 1
Header 2
Header 3
```

I want a sticky header as per image.
[image: I want this type of sticky header]

Comment: Please help me to share your knowledge. I have tried but not worked any solution.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var distanceFromTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (distanceFromTop >= $('.section-one').offset().top) {
        $('.section-one h1').addClass('fixed');
    }
    if (distanceFromTop >= $('.section-two').offset().top) {
        $('.section-two h1').addClass('fixed');
    }
    if (distanceFromTop >= $('.section-three').offset().top) {
        $('.section-three h1').addClass('fixed');
    }


    if (distanceFromTop >= $('.parent').height()) {
        $('.section-one h1').removeClass('fixed');
        $('.section-two h1').removeClass('fixed');
        $('.section-three h1').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

```css
.parent {
   position: relative;
}
.section-one, 
.section-two, 
.section-three { min-height: 100vh; }

.section-one { background: lightgray; }
.section-two { background: lightblue; }
.section-three { background: lightgreen; }

.section-one h1{
   position: sticky;
   top: 0;
   z-index: 9999;
}
.section-two h1{
   position: sticky;
   top: 0;
   z-index: 9999;
}
.section-three h1{
   position: sticky;
   top: 0;
   z-index: 9999;
}


.section-one h1.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
}
.section-two h1.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
}
.section-three h1.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
   <div class="section-one">
      <h1>Header 1</h1>
      <div class="content">
         content 123
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="section-two">
      <h1>Header 2</h1>
      <div class="content">
         content 789
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="section-three">
      <h1>Header 3</h1>
      <div class="content">
         content 456
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div style="height: 100vh; background: green;"></div>
```

Comment: Don't scroll Header 1 after completed section-one. If started section-two then Header 1 must be remaining at top.

Comment: I have updated my question. Please check it.

Comment: Sorry can you tell me again what were you looking for? Because each h1 is staying within it's section staying sticky when scrolling.

Comment: Now I get the question. It is not possible without js. Give me 1 minute. I'll update the answer the answer shortly.

Comment: https://codepen.io/rahulm1ll3k/pen/vYKVxVp
This should solve the problem.

Comment: The jQuery can be improved. You can control the heading position and styling by adding the .fixed to the h1 under each section like this : .section-one h1.fixed {}

Comment: If it helped please mark my reply as useful. Thank you.

Comment: Please update your answer.

Comment: Sorry I have updated the comment. Thank you for notifying me.